# Singly Linked List deleting last element

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

When calling this function the whole of the List is being deleted. Here's my code.

`head` is a global variable.
`struct node` is defined as `Node`.

```
void delete_last() {
    Node *temp = head, *prev;

    if (temp->next != NULL) {
        free(head);
        head = NULL;
        return;
    } else {
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        free(temp);
        prev->next = NULL;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ankit, you can (at least partially) format your code here by selecting the entire block of code and pressing Ctrl+K.

Comment: You should really clean up the indentation and spacing on this. It's a mess.

Comment: and you want to `free(head)` and set `head` to `NULL` when `(temp->next != NULL)`? Why?

Comment: you're checking the same condition in the `if` and in the `while` (under the `else` case). That means that the `while` will never get executed!

Comment: You probably mean `if (temp->next == NULL) { free(head); head = NULL; }'`. Wrong Boolean polarity in your test.

Comment: What if the list is already empty, and has no last node? You must consider all cases. The requirement "delete the last node" doesn't imply that the last node exists; computers are not people. You wouldn't ask a person to turn to the last page of a book that has no pages; but inside software, such things occur.

Comment: The problem with the code was with **if(temp->next==NULL)**. I used **if(temp->next!=NULL)** which was wrong. I figured this out later on.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems:

- the first test should be `if (temp->next == NULL)`
- you should test if the list is empty before dereferencing `head` or `temp`.

Here is a modified version:

```
void delete_last(void) {
    if (head != NULL) {
        Node *prev = NULL;
        Node *temp = head;
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        free(temp);
        if (prev) {
            prev->next = NULL;
        } else {
            head = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For starters the function has undefined behavior in case when `head` is equal to `NULL` due to these statements

```
Node *temp = head, *prev;

if (temp->next != NULL) {
```

And moreover the if statement with its sub-statement is logically incorrect.

The function can look the following way

```
void delete_last() 
{
    if ( head )
    {
        Node **last = &head;

        while ( ( *last )->next ) last = &( *last )->next;

        free( *last );
        *last = NULL;
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

Node *head;

int push_front( int value )
{
    Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->value = value;
        new_node->next = head;
        head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

void delete_last() 
{
    if ( head )
    {
        Node **last = &head;

        while ( ( *last )->next ) last = &( *last )->next;

        free( *last );
        *last = NULL;
    }
}

void output()
{
    for ( Node *current = head; current; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", current->value );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        push_front( i );
        output();
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    while ( head )
    {
        delete_last();
        output();
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 
1 0 
2 1 0 
3 2 1 0 
4 3 2 1 0 
5 4 3 2 1 0 
6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 
9 8 7 6 5 4 
9 8 7 6 5 
9 8 7 6 
9 8 7 
9 8 
9
```

Answer (score 1):

You're freeing the head node and setting it to null on the wrong condition.

```
if(temp->next!=NULL)
```

at the beginning should be

```
if(temp->next==NULL)
```

If the next node is *not* null, it means something is there and `temp` is not the last element.

Comment: You do need the condition or a link list with a single node will result in using an uninitialised prev pointer.

Comment: @Steve Good point. My fault for not testing it out before making that suggestion.